# Handling hash collisions when using linear probing

Tags: java, hashtable

I have read about hashtable and open adrdessing. If you want to insert the keys: 18,32,44 in an hashtable with size 13:

```
18 gets index 5 (18 modulus 13 = 5)
32 gets index 6 (32 modulus 13 = 6)
44 gets index 5 (44 modulus 13 = 5)
```

You'll get a collision because there are already something on index 5.

If you use linear probing you'll do `hashfunction = (key+i) modulus N` where `i = 0,1,2..` until you find an empty place in the hashtable. Then 44 will get be inserted at index 7.

What if you delete 32, and then you want to delete 44. You start by looking at `hashfunction(44)=5` - that was not 44, then `hashfunction(44 + 1) = 6` - that is empty. Then you might think that 44 is gone.  How do you mark a place in the hashtable, that the place is not really empty, but does not contain a key, and that you should keep looking for 44 at the next index?

If you then need to insert another key at index 6 then the key just overwrites the "mark" in the hashtable.

What could you use to mark an index - saying here has been an key, but has been deleted - so you continue to look at next index? You can't just write null or 0 because then either you think the key has been deleted (null) or that an key with value 0 has overwritten 44.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to handle hash tables using open addressing is to use state marks: `EMPTY`, `OCCUPIED` and `DELETED`. Note that there's an important distinction between `EMPTY`, which means the position has never been used and `DELETED`, which means it was used but got deleted.

When a value gets removed, the slot is marked as `DELETED`, not `EMPTY`. When you try to retrieve a value, you'll probe until you find a slot that's mark `EMPTY`; eg: you consider `DELETED` slots to be the same as `OCCUPIED`. Note that insertion can ignore this distinction - you *can* insert into a `DELETED` or `EMPTY` slot.

The question is tagged Java, which is a bit misleading because Java (or at least Oracle's implementation of it) does not use open addressing. Open addressing gets specially problematic when the load factor gets high, which causes hash collisions to occur much more often:

[image]

As you can see, there's a dramatic performance drop near the 0.7 mark. Most hashtables get resized once their load factor gets past a certain constant factor. Java for example doubles the size of its `HashMap` when the load factor gets past 0.75.

Comment: Thanks :) could i use ex enumerations for it? Because my hashtable contains integer.... So how to implement EMPTY,DELETED,OCCUPIED in an integer array?

Comment: @Anne I would use a separate data structure (eg: an array) that keeps track of these states.

Comment: I tend to implement linear probing with a Next field on each bucket pointing to the next collision.  When I remove a colliding item, I simply update the prior item's Next reference and add the removed bucket to the list of free buckets.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are trying to implement your own hash table (in contrast to using the Hashtable or HashMap included in java), so it's more a data structure question than a java question.

That being said, implementing a hash table with open addressing (such as linear probing) is not very efficient when it comes to removing elements. The normal solution is to "pull up" all elements that are in the wrong slot so there won't be any spaces in the probing.

There is some pseudo code describing this quite well at wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing

Comment: Thanks :) sorry about the java

Answer (score 0):

The hash table buckets aren't limited to storing a single value. So if two objects hash to the same location in the table they will both be stored. The collision only means that lookup will be slightly slower because when looking for the value with a key that hashes to a particular location it will need to check each entry to see if it matches

It sounds like you are describing a hash table where you only store a single entry and each index. The only way I can think to do that is to add a field to the structure storing the value that indicates if that position had a collision. Then when doing a lookup you'd check the key, if it was a match you have the value. If not, then you would check to see if there was a collision and then check the next position. On a removal you'd have to leave the collision marker but delete the value and key.

Comment: i know that you can use a hashtable where there can be more than one value at each index. But in my case i try not to do that. I only want one value per index. I dont need to mark that there has been an collision - i just revalidate a new index using linear probing. But on removal - how to i mark an index to "there have been an value but it is removed now, try next index to see if the number your looking after is that" - can i use ex -1 to mark the place with? But cant -1 also be a key?

Comment: @Anne: the collisions are handled for you by HashMap. HashMap stored a list of objects in each bucket. If hash codes are good, there's only one element in each bucket. If it's not, then some buckets have several keys. In the end, equals is used to compare keys. hashCode is only used to find the bucket.

Comment: but if i dont want to use a hashtable where there can be more objects at each index. My problem is not collision but remove. How to mark that there have been a value before when you traversal the hashtable after remove.

Comment: to simplify my question - how to mark an index that something have been at that index but is now removed - and i cannot use null.

Comment: @Anne what your describing is functionally equivalent to the way hash table works, your just trying to distribute the entries at other indexes instead of managing the list of entries at each index. Anyhow, I don't see the difference between 'marking there was a collision' with storing '-1' to mark a place where a value was removed.

Comment: yeah i know it is the same as using lists at each index. Im just trying to understand how the remove method could work if i dont use lists. Collision is when a key get an index where there a already stored something. The mark should inserted at the index where i remove - it has nothing with collision to do. I just need to see after a removal that something has been  on that index. A sign or something. My hashtable is an array with holds integer. But if put -1 in as a mark after a removal then the hashtable think that it is a key with at value. but is is not - it is only a mark.

Comment: The question asks about hash tables that use open addressing, unlike Java's hash tables (which use chaining).

Answer (score 0):

If you use a hash table which uses this approach (which none of the built in hash collections do) you need traverse all the latter keys to see if they need to be moved up (to avoid holes). Some might be for the same hash value and some might be collisions for unrelated hash codes. If you do this you are not left with any holes.  For a hash map which is not too full, this shouldn't create much overhead.

Comment: but if i dont want to moved all the keys when i remove, do you know which mark (a sign or an integer that the hashtable do not think is a key) i could use until the index get overwritten by a new key. If i use ex -1 as a mark, the hashtable thinks it is a key with a value. Doesn't it?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that when you do a lookup you need to check after every marked and unmarked key (i.e. potentially every key even when the map is empty) You can't stop when you get an empty entry.